# Mouse left click stops working after a while in Chrome on angularjs app

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-chrome

After having browser screen out of focus for a while and working in another window, going back to that screen mouse click event have stopped working and I'm not able to click any `<a/>` links or trigger any `ngClick` direcitves.

This doesn't happen on any other site, so my guess it has to do something with my angular app, but the problem is - I cannot 100% replicate the issue and I don't know where to look for the problem.

I'm wondering has anyone else had this same issue and if they have resolved it.

**How to make the click event work**: Click on any element in developer tools to highlight it and voila, the click works again.

Notes:

- Left click / Context menu works
- Mouse position events work
- Mouse enter/leave events work
- `<a/>` links are not wired with any jQuery or any other event handlers that I know of
- **Update 1**: Cannot seem to replicate this issue in IE11

Browser set-up

- Chrome: Version 49.0.2623.112 m
- Developer tools always open

Comment: I dont have exactly the same issues, but I am having trouble using the developer tools in exactly the same version of Chrome, also with Angular. Specifically, I'm unable to select or edit CSS. It's interpreting my clicks as 'highlight this text', rather than 'edit this field'. Perhaps unrelated, but since there are 2 common factors I figured it's worth mentioning.

Comment: @tom that issue is due to properties being comstantly updated, therefore chaning the value it changes back instantly. If you go to source and stop js execution you will be able to chnage the valuew